# Run IndexOf more than one time JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, indexof

How to search multiple same values and look if it meets the conditions without regex? Suppose that I have this string `***6**5****8*9***2`
What I need to do is to check if the string has at least three times `***` altogether and then if the number before and after the `***` sums 11. In the example given, these conditions are met because: First, the string has three `***` altogether, and then 9 + 2 is 11.

I have solved this problem using regex, match, and replace, but how I can do it without applying to those solutions.

I have tried to do this without regex but it did not work because indexOf is only giving me one result:

```
string = "***6**5****8*9***2";

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
     let where = (string.indexOf("***"));
     let a = parseInt(string.charAt(where - 1)); 
     let b = parseInt(string.charAt(where + 3));
    if (a + b == 11){
        isTrue = true;             
    }
   }
```

Comment: [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) takes a parameter telling it where to start looking. So in each iteration, use the previous value of `where + 3` as the parameter.

Comment: split the string after getting index to last (last index of string).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, So i should not use IndexOf for this case?

Comment: What @JohnnyMopp is saying is that once you get a `true` result from `indexOf()`, you should record that index in a variable and then use that as the starting position for the next use of `indexOf()`.

Comment: @SunnyGoel But what will happen is the string is 28***34*5****, the string has *** and 8 + 3 = 11, so this string is also valid.

Comment: However, I just noticed the question says _at least three_ so it will take a little more work to find the digits.

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks @ScottMarcus

Comment: @Fiera28 so first you have to find the *** then you need to check its first prefix character and last prefix character after checking this condition. you will need to break if addition condition not met

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the string by stars amd keep the starts in the array then check if the value starts with a star, check the length and the left and right element for sum.

```js
var string = "***6**5****8*9***2",
    parts = string.split(/(\*+)/),
    result = parts.some((s, i, { [i - 1]: l, [i + 1]: r }) =>
        s[0] === '*' && s.length >= 3 && +l + +r === 11
    );

console.log(result);
console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a solution based off of your existing code:

```js
string = "***6**5****8*9***2***4";

let where = 0;
// Skip leading *
while (where < string.length && '*' == string.charAt(where)) {
  where += 1;
}

while (true) {
  // Find three stars based on previous result
  where = string.indexOf("***", where);
  // No more triples
  if (where == -1) break;
  // Convert to digit - will be NaN if not a digit
  let a = parseInt(string.charAt(where - 1));
  // Find trailing digit
  let j = where + 1;
  // Skip to next non * char
  while (j < string.length && '*' == string.charAt(j)) {
    j += 1;
  }
  // No matches - quit
  if (j == string.length) break;
  // Parse digit
  let b = parseInt(string.charAt(j));
  // Do the math
  if (!isNaN(a) && !isNaN(b)){
    console.log(`${a} + ${b} = ${a+b}`);
  }
  where = j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple Parser.I hope it can help you

```js
string = "***6**5****8*9***2";

class Parser {
  static parse(string) {
    var lexer = new Lexer(string);
    var token = lexer.getToken();
    var prevNumberToken  = null ;
    while (token.type !== TOKEN_TYPE_END) {
      if(token.type === TOKEN_TYPE_NUMBER){
        if(prevNumberToken && prevNumberToken.value + token.value === 11 ) {
          return true;
        }
        prevNumberToken = token ;
      } else if(token.type !== TOKEN_TYPE_THREESTARS){
        prevNumberToken = null ;
      }
      token = lexer.getToken();
    }
    return false;
  }
}


class Lexer {
  constructor(string) {
    this._string = string;
    this._index = -1;
    this._len = string.length;
  }

  getToken() {
    if (this._index < 0) {
      this._index = 0;
      return new Token(TOKEN_TYPE_START, '', -1);
    }
    if (this._index >= this._len) {
      return new Token(TOKEN_TYPE_END, '', this._len);
    }
    if (this._string[this._index] === "*") {
      return this._getStarToken()
    } else {
      return this._getNumberToken();
    }
  }

  _getStarToken() {
    var stars = "";
    var i = this._index;
    while (this._index < this._len && this._string[this._index] === "*") {
      stars += "*";
      this._index++;
    }
    if (stars.length === 3) {
      return new Token(TOKEN_TYPE_THREESTARS, stars, i)
    }
    return new Token(TOKEN_TYPE_STARS, stars, i)
  }
  _getNumberToken() {
    var numbers = "";
    var i = this._index;
    while (this._index < this._len && this._string[this._index] !== "*") {
      if (this._string[this._index] >= "0" && this._string[this._index] <= "90") {
        numbers += this._string[this._index];
        this._index++;
      } else {
        throw new Error("invalid character")
      }
    }
    return new Token(TOKEN_TYPE_NUMBER, parseInt(numbers), i);
  }

}


class Token {
  constructor(type, value, index) {
    this._type = type
    this._index = index
    this._value = value
  }
  get type() { return this._type }
  get index() { return this._index }
  get value() { return this._value }
}

const TOKEN_TYPE_START = 1;
const TOKEN_TYPE_NUMBER = 2;
const TOKEN_TYPE_THREESTARS = 4;
const TOKEN_TYPE_STARS = 8;
const TOKEN_TYPE_END = 16;

console.log(Parser.parse(string));
```